# Do I need an applicationserver for Java WebSocketServer

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websocket, glassfish

I am completely new to java and now I need your help.

The different between JavaSE and JavaEE is clear to me.
But why do I need for JavaEE coding an application server.
Or lets say, I try to code a websocket server in java and i did it with this tutorial:
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html

But do I need an application server like in this case glassfish???

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. You need an application server to write JEE applications, but you don't need an application server to support Websockets: a Servlet container will do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Java EE is the *specification*, and [Glassfish](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/glassfish/overview/index.html) is Oracle's *implementation* of Java EE. Glassfish can run the byte code that is generated from compiling your source code. You must have some implementation of Java EE in order to actually run the code that you write using Java EE. An alternative server for WebSocket capabilities is [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) from Apache.

It's similar to how a JRE is an implementation of Java SE. You must have a JRE in order to run the code that you write using the Java SE specification.

Comment: Tomcat is not a JEE container. Hotspot is a an internal JVM technology, not an entire Java SE implementation.

Comment: @EJP Right, I didn't mean to suggest Tomcat did all that Glassfish did, so I didn't say that. So does Oracle have a name for their full implementation of Java SE? Otherwise I just know it as the JRE.

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for your helo.

Comment: Can someone please provide me a good tutorial for JavaEE coding with application server. Because at the moment I am not comletly sure how to setup everything so that I can deploy/run several codes on one app-server. In addition, how can I overwrite the WebSocketWrapper (Class which initiale the WebSocketServer) from the glassfish application server. The TUT above only descripe how to code the Endpoint behavoir, but I need to use a JDBC DB connection and a trigger, so I would like to start those instance afterwards the WebSocketServer. At the moment it is reverse.